# Is there any benefit to organic apple cider vinegar over processed apple cider vinegar?

Tags: nutrition, vinegar

This [website](http://www.globalhealingcenter.com/natural-health/the-benefits-of-apple-cider-vinegar/) makes the claim that raw organic apple cider vinegar (ACV) is better for the health than "clear" ACV.  I've heard this claim made before in the realm of animal husbandry. Has anyone actually studied organic ACV to determine if there is really any difference?

Comment: And I wonder if the processed one has any real benefit.

Comment: I see a lot of claims on that web-site, but not that organic is better than non-organic apple-cider vinegar. Can you please quote an example of the claim you are interested in?

Comment: That website is terrible. It's even contradicting itself! "ACV is better than clear vinegar, because it has acetic acid"... No comment...

Comment: @Oddthinking I'd seen the claim before and I thought it was on that website. I confess I was a little lazy in double checking the reference. I'll edit my question with the link I had previously seen.

Comment: I'm not sure about apple cider, but organic food in general has absolutely no benefit over non-organic food. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_food

Comment: Regardless of the myriad woo surrounding apple cider vinegar, "raw" cider products are precisely why we invented and use Pasteurization: food-borne pathogens are no fun. http://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodborneIllnessContaminants/default.htm